# Length of a probability vector?

Tags: probability, distributions, deterministic, vector

I'm doing some work on probability vectors, and came across the idea of probability vector length as a measure of how deterministic a probability vector is, as calculated using this equation:

[image]

The values are supposed to range between 1 (the most certain vector) and 1/n (when all options have equal probability). My issue is though that probability vector length only seems to be mentioned on Wikipedia and one other website ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_vector) and [here](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-vector/)). I was wondering if anyone knows of any more reputable sources on probability vector lengths e.g. books or papers because I'd like to be more confident that this statistic is calculating what I hope it is. Alternatively if probability vector length is known by a different name, for example in relation to matrices, that would be really useful too. I'd be grateful even if people could confirm if this is a concept that they have previously encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quantity is certainly calculating the length of $\mathbf p$ since
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n  p_i^2} 
  &= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (p_i-\bar p + \bar p)^2}
\\&= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (p_i-\bar p)^2 + \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n2\bar p(p_i-\bar p)}_{=0}+\sum_{i=1}^n\bar p^2}
\\&= \sqrt{n\sigma^2 + 1/n},
\end{align}
since $\bar p=1/n$.

Comment: This seems pretty good, but I still have two questions. #1 - Why does the sum of the mean squared on line two become the mean on line three instead of the mean squared? #2 - Based on line 1, are you saying the length can also be found by summing the square of each probability in the vector and then square rooting it? Thanks

Comment: You sum $\bar p^2$ $n$ times which gives you $n \bar p^2=n (1/n)^2=1/n$.

Comment: Because that is the definition of the length of the vector.